# Apache hive - How to limit partitions in show command

Tags: hive

Is there any way to limit the number of Hive partitions while listing the partitions in `show` command?

I have a Hive table which has around 500 partitions and I wanted the latest partition alone. The show command list all the partitions. I am using this partition to find out the location details. I do not have access to metastore to query the details and the partition location is where the actual data resides.

I tried set hive.limit.query.max.table.partition=1 but this does not affect the metastore query. So, is there any other way to limit the partitions listed?

Thank you,
Revathy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from the command line?

If so you can get your desired with something like this:

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false;show partitions table_name;" | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "BAD" way to obtain what you want. You can treat the partitions columns like other columns and extract them into a select with limit query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT partition_column  
FROM partitioned_table
ORDER BY partition_column
LIMIT 1;
```

The only way to filter a SHOW PARTION is using PARTITION:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS partitioned_table PARTION ( partitioned_column = "somevalue" );
```